# How to have conditional statement for mat-paginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying mat-paginator and it is working. But, when I keep it in *ngIf it fails to work.

```
<mat-paginator  (page)="changePage($event)"
           [length]="100"
           [pageSize]="20">
</mat-paginator>
```

Above one Works.

```
<div *ngIf="!spinner">
    <mat-paginator  (page)="changePage($event)"
           [length]="100"
           [pageSize]="20">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

When I use *ngIf the page doesn't move. The paginator appears. However, we can't move to next page having conditional statement. Why does this happen?

I want to have conditional statement for paginator and the paginator should be displayed. Is there any other way for using conditional statement for paginator?

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: Can you share stackblitz for the same ?

Comment: I dont know what's the problem but why not simply using a conditional class of `display: none;` (if you're using bootstrap just add:  `[class.d-none]="spinner"` )

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to work"?

Comment: The paginator doesn't change to next page and remains in same one. It doesn't even give any error on console.

Comment: I don't see any issues with paginator . Check this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuugfh

Comment: @CruelEngine I agree with you that the paginator appears when you click toggle button. Now, try this case where you go to next page in paginator and then click  toggle button. The paginator automatically moves to first page. Hope you understood the issue.

Comment: @MaruthiEranki please see my answer which is based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement specified in the comment:

There is an option to set the page selected index explicitly in `mat-paginator`. It can be done using `pageIndex` input .

All you have to do is as soon as the page changes , save the page Index in a variable and pass the index as input to the `mat-paginator` .

In your html , make the following changes :

```
<div *ngIf='!spinner'>
  <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" (page)="changePage($event)" [pageIndex]='pageIndex'>
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

in your ts file :

```
  changePage(event : PageEvent){
    console.log("i'm called");
    this.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
  }
```

I have modified the example that i shared in the comment that uses the above logic [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuugfh)

Comment: Thanks man, It worked with [pageIndex]. But, still I didn't get why it didn't work without pageIndex. Is paginator refreshing because of *ngIf?

Comment: @MaruthiEranki , If you use ``ngIf`` , your component gets destroyed when if is ``false`` and it is initialized again when ``true``

Comment: @MaruthiEranki if my answer has solved your  problem, please consider marking it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was hiding the paginator conditionally with CSS. Set its display to none when you don't want it to show up. It's not ideal on a design level but it produces the right UI results. With tailwind, I did something like this:

```html
    <mat-paginator 
      class="{{conditionIsTrue ? 'hidden' : 'block'}}" 
      ....other properties
    >
    </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: The problem is taht, when we assing the mat-paginator, the mat-paginator not exist. You can, enclosed in a setTimeout, when the condition it's true, asign the mat-paginator. NOTE: you can also use `[style.display]="!condition?'none':null`"